# Building JavaFX app in IntelliJ IDEA using maven

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, javafx, maven-plugin

I've encountered some difficulties trying to build JavaFX app using maven. The app work just fine from IDE. I run maven package task and it creates JAR file. The problem is this file doesn't run. I've checked included manifest and there wasn't entry point. I've added it, but the file still doesn't run. That's how the manifest looks now (the last string was added manually):

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.6.3
Built-By: Комп
Build-Jdk: 15
Main-Class: org.example.App
```

The pom file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>org.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>Refinement</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>


  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
      <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
      <version>11.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx-maven-plugin -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
      <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.4</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.4</version>
        <configuration>
          <mainClass>org.example.App</mainClass>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>


</project>
```

And build log

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15\bin\java.exe" -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=C:\Users\Комп\Documents\javaProjects\Refinement "-Dmaven.home=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.3.3\plugins\maven\lib\maven3" "-Dclassworlds.conf=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.3.3\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\bin\m2.conf" "-Dmaven.ext.class.path=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.3.3\plugins\maven\lib\maven-event-listener.jar" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.3.3\lib\idea_rt.jar=65494:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.3.3\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.3.3\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.6.0.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.3.3\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\boot\plexus-classworlds.license" org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher -Didea.version=2020.2.2 package
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] -----------------------< org.example:Refinement >-----------------------
[INFO] Building Refinement 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ Refinement ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\Комп\Documents\javaProjects\Refinement\src\main\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ Refinement ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ Refinement ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\Комп\Documents\javaProjects\Refinement\src\test\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ Refinement ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ Refinement ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: C:\Users\Комп\Documents\javaProjects\Refinement\target\surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running org.example.AppTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.052 sec

Results :

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ Refinement ---
[INFO] Building jar: C:\Users\Комп\Documents\javaProjects\Refinement\target\Refinement-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  35.456 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-10-06T12:04:09+03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Updated

I've tried to launch JAR file from CLI and get the error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.example.App
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application
```

Maybe I have to include JavaFX classes in the JAR file? I'm not sure if user's machine will have JavaFX installed, and I don't want to rely on this.

Also I've tried to rebuild the pom file as shown in [Building a minimal JavaFX 11 application with Maven](https://webtechie.be/post/2019-04-01-pijava-part-4-building-a-minimal-javafx-11-application-with-maven/) article. This new version also throws an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
        at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:151)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:825)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:723)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:646)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:604)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:168)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
        at org.example.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:5)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javafx.application.Application
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:606)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:168)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
        ... 10 more
```

Looks more verbose, but the essence is the same on my mind.

Checked PATH variable, it points to JavaFX lib folder.

Comment: What error do you get when running application? Please try steps from this article: https://webtechie.be/post/2019-04-01-pijava-part-4-building-a-minimal-javafx-11-application-with-maven/

Comment: Thank you, I've updated the description

Comment: Let me jump into this problem as @y.bedrov was so kind to refer to my blog ;-) Seems you are not linking to a correct JavaFX path, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1136420/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javafx-application-application --> "java --module-path $FX-PATH --add-modules javafx.controls -jar sample.jar" where $FX-PATH should be set or replaced with mentioned JavaFX path. Or maybe use the LibericaJDK which includes JavaFX: https://webtechie.be/post/2020-04-08-installing-java-and-javafx-on-raspberry-pi/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start a new JavaFX project, it's a good idea to visit this (brand new) website: https://start.gluon.io/. You will get a ZIP containing all the files and a README to get you started immediately.

For a basic app, deselect all "Gluon Features", "CloudLink" and "Attach".

[image: start.gluon.io selections in web interface]

[image: start.gluon.io preview]

[image: start.gluon.io downloaded ZIP]